# Allowing multiple element to work in an array

Tags: ruby

I have this array. `@stuff = ["pop", "corn", "apple", "banana"]`

I wanted to make a message that would able to work anything that is included in @stuff, something like this...?

`if @msg =~ /#{@stuff}/i` => do something

I could do this way, but it would take a long time to do each single element in @stuff.

```
if @msg =~ /(.*)/i
     if $1.to_s == "pop" #do something
     elsif $1.to_s == "corn" #do something
     elsif $1.to_s == "apple" #do something
     elsif $1.to_s == "banana" #do something
     end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really unclear what the regular expression accomplishes. You can test whether a value is in an array by simply using `include?`:

```
if @stuff.include?(msg)
  #do something
end
```

If you want to compare in a case-insensitive way, you can convert both to lower-case strings:

```
if @stuff.map(&:downcase).include?(@msg.downcase)
```

If you *really* want to use a regular expression (you shouldn't in this case), you can join the items with `|` and wrap them in parenthesis to produce a regular expression with a series of "OR" matches....

```
/(#{@stuff.join('|')})/i =~ @msg
```

Comment: The 3rd one is what I need - Awesome! Thanks!

Comment: @Charles Again, you shouldn't use regular expressions for this.